# random generator with specific outputs

Tags: random

my teacher ask me to create a c++ program that generate n number of random integers where n is also random and will output the maximum,minimum random integer and average. Im having a hard time on this one

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read about how to ask homework questions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions, and also about how to ask questions in general: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please add your effort and ask specific question where you are getting error/unexpected output